# spray-json. Как получить List объектов из json

Tags: scala, akka-http

Использую `akka-http-spray-json 10.0.9`.

Моделька:

```
case class Person(id: Long, name: String, age: Int)
```

Получаю json строку `jsonStr` со списком персон и пытаюсь ее распарсить:

```
implicit val personFormat: RootJsonFormat[Person] = jsonFormat3(Person)

val json = jsonStr.parseJson
val persons = json.convertTo[List[Person]]
```

Ошибка:

> Object expected in field 'id'

Answer (score 0):

Мой код в вопросе корректен. Проблема нашлась во входной строке `jsonStr`, которая оказалась валидным json объектом, но неверного формата.